# Copy and paste from one column to another in MS_Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Fellow overflowers,

I am working with a database to sort several other databases and change some values so my scada application can use the values in the database.

Now I have encountered the following problem:

I have a column called "Name"  and in this column are string values like this one:

```
S1\SVS_AK\STS\Status[7]
```

From this string I'd like to cut (or copy, doesn't really make a difference eitherway) the "[7]" part and paste this behind whatever I have in a different column.

So for example:

I have a column "Address" and a column "Name"
I want to take the [7] from the Name Column and paste that behind the already existing string "DB32,7.3" wich exists in the column Address

How can I possibly do this? Preferably with a query

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
UPDATE ATable SET AField2 = Mid(AField,instr(AField,"[")) & AField2
```

You might like to add

```
WHERE AField Like "*[[]*"
```

[ is a special character, so it need to be bracketed for the Like statement, as illustrated.